# Comparison of Two Populations in ARIMA Interrupted Time Series

Tags: r, time-series, arima, intervention-analysis

I am trying to do a comparison of the impact of COVID-19 on cancer diagnoses in the US. I have fit an ARIMA model to all cancer site monthly incidence rates for the US from January 2018 to December 2020 with a pulse in March-May 2020 and a proposed step change from June-December 2020. I feel comfortable with this model and all the diagnostics.

What I would like to do now is compare the relative impact on two mutually exclusive population subgroups, say Urban vs Rural population. In particular, I am interested in comparing the size of the pulse disruption between the two and the size of the step change between the two. In my mind, there are two options for doing this, but I'm not sure which is correct:

1. Use the ARIMA parameters from the US model, fit them to the population subgroups individually, and compare the coefficients of the pulse and step regressors between them.
2. Fit individual models to each of the population subgroups and compare the coefficients of the pulse and step regressors between them.

Any guidance on what approach is more statistically sound? I have searched for subgroup comparisons between different time series using ARIMAs, but have not had any luck. Thanks.